# revise href attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have a link like this:

```
<a href="http://thissite.org/thisfolder/21/thispage.php">
```

What I want to do is revise it but keep part of it eg:

```
<a href="http://thissite.org/thatfolder/21/thatpage.php">
```

Can this be done with Jquery or js?

I know I can replace href property with jquery but I need to leave part of the url ("21") and just change the text before and after it.

I was thinking maybe grab the href property, stick it in a variable and take it apart and put it back together somehow.

Any help with this would be largely appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call `replace` in a property setter function:

```
$('a').attr('href', function(index, old) {
    return old.replace(/thisfolder/i, 'thatfolder');
});
```

Comment: Great answer. I used to always store the original attribute value in a variable, then set it like `$('a').attr('href', oldHref.replace(...);`. Didn't know you could pass a function in as the second argument.

Comment: @maxedison: Yes; this is a very useful feature.  Note that your way won't work if there are multiple elements unless you call `.each`.

Comment: Right, I'd either do that or use a more specific selector. But that just makes your solution all the more elegant. I assume this can be done pretty much anywhere, no? Like in `.css()`, etc?

Comment: @maxedison: Everywhere except `.data`.  (even in `.append` and friends)  Check the docs.

Answer (score 1):

A rough way of doing this would be:

```
// "elem" is the element, for example elem=document.getElementById('link_to_change')
var url = elem.getAttribute("href").split("/");
url.pop();
url.push("thatpage.php");
elem.setAttribute("href",url.join("/"));
```

Comment: Ah yes. Well I guess you could `pop()` up all the ones you need and then `push()` them back on, but then it starts getting messy.